# NTService looking for wrong config file

Tags: windows, c#-4.0, wix, wix3.8, component-services

I'm working on moving a set of installers from VS2010 to WIX and have encountered an error with our NT Service applications.

After creating and installing the NT Service using the WIX installer, the service is not looking for the app.config named as you would expect (ApplicationName.exe.config).  Our application name is akin to XXX.YYYYYYYY and when injecting the debugger into the service during start up, i can see that it is looking for XXX.config instead of XXX.YYYYYYY.exe.config.

I've tried running the application via the console and when I do, it looks for the correct app.config file name.  Using the VS2010 installer also has the service looking for the correct app.config file name.

Is there some setting in wxi3.8 that I am missing, or putting the incorrect value into, that would cause this?  Here is the segment of the wxs that controls the service:

```
<Component Id="Service" Guid="DCE18608-D25F-4DC0-9E1B-C2E3575D0BFE">
<File Id="ServiceComponentMain" Name="$(var.XXX.YYYYYYY.TargetName)" Source="$(var.HHG.SpecOrderLoadSync.TargetPath)"
      DiskId="1" Vital="yes" KeyPath="yes"/>
<ServiceInstall Id="Service" Name="$(var.XXX.YYYYYYY.TargetName)" Type="ownProcess" DisplayName="$(var.XXX.YYYYYYY.TargetName)"
                Description="$(var.XXX.YYYYYYY.TargetName)" Start="auto" Account="NT AUTHORITY\LocalService" ErrorControl="normal">
    <util:PermissionEx User="Everyone" ServicePauseContinue="yes" ServiceQueryStatus="yes"
                       ServiceStart="no" ServiceStop="yes" ServiceUserDefinedControl="yes"/>
</ServiceInstall>
<ServiceControl Id="Service" Stop="both" Remove="both" Name="$(var.XXX.YYYYYYY.TargetName)" Wait="no"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured this out after digging around the registery.  It appears that with my current wsx file it isn't registering the full path to the executable including ".exe" at the end.  This is what is causing the config file name to be confused.  Why in the world this makes a difference is beyond me, but just another thing to annoy me about windows i guess...

To fix, changing the Name on the File element in the segment above to be $(var.XXX.YYYYYYY.TargetName).exe instead of just $(var.XXX.YYYYYYY.TargetName) seems to work.